# Spring Security not processing pre/post annotations

Tags: spring-security

I'm trying to get pre/post annotations working with a web application, but for some reason nothing is happening with spring-security.

web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/rvaContext-business.xml
        /WEB-INF/rvaContext-security.xml  
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Spring security filter -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rva</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rva</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rva/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

rvaContext-security.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>

<http use-expressions="true">
    <form-login login-page="/login" />
    <logout />
    <remember-me />
</http>
...
```

LoginController class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(ModelMap map){
        map.addAttribute("title", "Login: AD Credentials");
        return("login");
    }

    @RequestMapping("/secure")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
    public String secure(ModelMap map){
        return("secure");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To enable secuity annotations on the controllers you should declare `<security:global-method-security .../>` in the context where controllers are declared, that is in `rva-servlet.xml`.

Comment: You saved me few hours of usefulness debugging... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, you need to redefine `<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>` in the config file which is also used for your controllers. In **Spring Roo** this is **webmvc-config.xml**. When configuring security with Roo, the config file applicationContext-security.xml is initially configured to enable those annotations. This was a little confusing...

Answer (score 0):

See [Spring Security FAQ](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/faq.html#faq-method-security-in-web-context) (emphasis mine).

> In a Spring web application, the application context which holds the
>   Spring MVC beans for the dispatcher servlet is often separate from the
>   main application context. It is often defined in a file called
>   myapp-servlet.xml, where “myapp” is the name assigned to the Spring
>   DispatcherServlet in web.xml. An application can have multiple
>   DispatcherServlets, each with its own isolated application context.
>   The beans in these “child” contexts are not visible to the rest of the
>   application. The “parent” application context is loaded by the
>   ContextLoaderListener you define in your web.xml and is visible to all
>   the child contexts. This parent context is usually where you define
>   your security configuration, including the 
>   element). As a result any security constraints applied to methods in
>   these web beans will not be enforced, since the beans cannot be seen
>   from the DispatcherServlet context. You need to either move the
>    declaration to the web context or moved the
>   beans you want secured into the main application context.
>
> **Generally we would recommend applying method security at the service
>   layer rather than on individual web controllers.**

If you apply pointcuts to service layer you only need to set `<global-method-security>` in your app's security context.