# Spring Security annotations not consistent?

Tags: spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

I noticed that on my code, I can successfully annotate methods on services classes (@Service) with both @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN") and @RolesAllowed("ROLE_ADMIN"). It works. Though, when I move the same annotations to the controller classes (@Controller) only @Secured gets activated whereas @RolesAllowed is ignored. I configured my root applicationContext with

```
<security:global-method-security 
          jsr250-annotations="enabled" 
          secured-annotations="enabled"/>
```

Why isn't @RollesAllowed applicable to controller classes while @Secured is?

Comment: Question why are you using both?

Comment: So that I learn how to use them and then can have a more educated opinion on which I will pick. Do you know why am I seeing the behaviour explained in the question?

Comment: I believe it is because you are trying to use two sets of annotations that are similar, but not the same.  As far as I recall `@RolesAllowed` is the pure Spring way of doing things, and `@Secured` is specifically tied to Spring Security.

Comment: They both work at the '@Service' level. I want to understand why in my controller the '@Secured' works, but the '@RolesAllowed' is ignored. Is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: Can you post the annotated classes + the full config file?  That will help some of us debug this, also what server are you deploying to, spring version number, spring security number, and java version.

Comment: Thanks for your help and time Woot4Moo! I actually found why it was not working: "To enable security annotations on the controllers you should declare <security:global-method-security .../> in the context where controllers are declared" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524962/spring-security-not-processing-pre-post-annotations)

Comment: @Woot4Moo, thanks for your time on helping out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why @RolesAllowed was working in the Service level (but not in Controllers) was due to a misconfiguration on my part. To make it work, I had to declare the global-method-security in the same configuration file (context) where my Controllers are scanned for. For example:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="mrpomario.springcore.mvc.controller"/>
<security:global-method-security 
          jsr250-annotations="enabled" 
          secured-annotations="enabled"/>
```

Comment: This isn't quite consistent with your question. If the declaration was not visible from the application context containing the controllers, none of the security annotations would work at all. However, you say that one was working but one wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing different annotations isn't guaranteed to produce consistent behaviour.

From [the manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-method-security):

> You can enable more than one type of annotation in the same application, but only one type should be used for any interface or class as the behaviour will not be well-defined otherwise. If two annotations are found which apply to a particular method, then only one of them will be applied.